# how to generate the merged string consisting of values from JSON in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Input Data in a json file:

```
[{
    "orders": {
        "order_id": {
            "path": "orderid",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "customer_id": {
            "path": "customers.customerId",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "offer_id": {
            "path": "Offers.Offerid",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "products": {
        "product_id": {
            "path": "product_id",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "product_name": {
            "path": "products.productname",
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}]
```

For Orders: I am trying to generate concated string with values from path,type and columnkey using which i want to execute in a spark sql statement.

cast(orderid as string) as order_id -- orderid from from path key,string comes from type and order_id comes orders.order_id key

```
output
cast(orderid as string) as order_id,cast(customers.customerId as string) as customer_id,cast(Offers.Offerid as string) as offer_id
```

Comment: You can create a case class modeling the data in the json file.
and use a json processing library, spray for exemple. And finally create your string using the case class attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

```
df.show(false)
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|orders                                                                       |products                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|{{customers.customerId, string}, {Offers.Offerid, string}, {orderid, string}}|{{product_id, string}, {products.productname, string}}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
val columName = "Orders".toLowerCase
```

```
val outputExpr = s"""
    concat_ws(
        ', ',
        transform(
            map_entries(
                ${columName}),
                e -> CONCAT('CAST( ',e.value.path, ' AS ',e.value.type,' )',' AS ',e.key)
            )
        ) AS output
    """
```

```
val schema = "map<string, struct<path:string,type:string>>"
```

```
df
.withColumn(
  columName,
  expr(
   s"""
     from_json(
        to_json(${columName}),
        '${schema}'
     )
    """
  )
)
.selectExpr(outputExpr)
.show(false)
```

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|output                                                                                                                                    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CAST( customers.customerId AS string ) AS customer_id, CAST( Offers.Offerid AS string ) AS offer_id, CAST( orderid AS string ) AS order_id|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: how to generate the same output if i am reading the json content as string in a variable

Comment: please create new question more details input & expected output.

Comment: here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78198866/how-to-convert-a-string-json-to-scala-dataframe