# How to convert a string json to scala dataframe?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a string json which i am trying to create a dataframe. using below code i can achieve but the environment i am building the jar, there its complaining about toDS. is there any other way t achieve?

```
val abc="""[{"orders":{"order_id":{"path":"orderid","type":"string"},"customer_id":{"path":"customers.customerId","type":"string"},"offer_id":{"path":"Offers.Offerid","type":"string"}},"products":{"product_id":{"path":"product_id","type":"string"},"product_name":{"path":"products.productname","type":"string"}}}]"""

val df = spark.read.json(Seq(abc).toDS());
df.show()
```

[image]

Comment: what was the issue with `toDS` .. can you please post that ?

Comment: value toDS is not a member of Seq[String]

Comment: you can import spark.implicits._ and try again

Answer (score 0):

You can import spark implicits using `import spark.implicits._` it should work.

```
scala> spark
res23: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@8373d56

scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._

scala> val abc="""[{"orders":{"order_id":{"path":"orderid","type":"string"},"customer_id":{"path":"customers.customerId","type":"string"},"offer_id":{"path":"Offers.Offerid","type":"string"}},"products":{"product_id":{"path":"product_id","type":"string"},"product_name":{"path":"products.productname","type":"string"}}}]"""
abc: String = [{"orders":{"order_id":{"path":"orderid","type":"string"},"customer_id":{"path":"customers.customerId","type":"string"},"offer_id":{"path":"Offers.Offerid","type":"string"}},"products":{"product_id":{"path":"product_id","type":"string"},"product_name":{"path":"products.productname","type":"string"}}}]

scala> val df = spark.read.json(Seq(abc).toDS())
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [orders: struct<customer_id: struct<path: string, type: string>, offer_id: struct<path: string, type: string> ... 1 more field>, products: struct<product_id: struct<path: string, type: string>, product_name: struct<path: string, type: string>>]

scala> df.show(false)
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|orders                                                                       |products                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|{{customers.customerId, string}, {Offers.Offerid, string}, {orderid, string}}|{{product_id, string}, {products.productname, string}}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```